# perl to delete consecutive duplicate lines

Tags: regex, perl, delete-row

I want to delete the consecutive duplicate lines. i.e. for example

```
**test.txt**
car
speed is good
bike 
slower than car
plane
super fast
super fast
bullet train 
super fast
```

This removes all the duplicate lines except the 1st occurance.

```
perl -ne 'print unless $a{$_}++'
```

But i want the ouput to be

```
    **test.txt**
    car
    speed is good
    bike 
    slower than car
    plane
    super fast
    bullet train 
    super fast
```

I tried this oneliner but this doesnt do anything but just prints the input.

```
perl -00 -F'<\w+>|</\w+>' -i.bak -lane 'foreach(@F){if ($_=~/\w+/ && ($a ne $_)){print "$_";$a=$_;}}'
```

How to do this???

Comment: If you're on Linux (or have Cygwin on Windows) use [uniq(1)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?uniq) instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
perl -ne 'print unless (defined($prev) && ($_ eq $prev)); $prev=$_'
```

Comment: Time for a file with 1M lines: 0.727 seconds.

Answer (score 10):

Why don't you just use `uniq`?

```
uniq file.txt
```

Results:

```
car
speed is good
bike 
slower than car
plane
super fast
bullet train 
super fast
```

You can also do this with `awk`:

```
awk 'line != $0; { line = $0 }' file.txt
```

Comment: Time for a file with 1M lines: uniq: 1.579 seconds. awk: 10.615 seconds.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ perl -ne 'print $_ unless $_ eq $prev; $prev = $_'
```

Comment: This will warn about `$prev` being undefined

Comment: No, it won't.  "perl -nwe" would.

Comment: Time for a file with 1M lines: 0.646 seconds. After several tests: Always a bit faster than epsalons answer.

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to keep track of how many duplicates were suppressed and only skip consecutive duplicates.

While this is not exactly what the OP asked, it is a variant which others may find useful:

```
perl -ne 'if (defined($pr) && ($_ eq $pr)) {$cnt++;} else {print "... (+$cnt)\n" if ($cnt); print; $cnt=0; $pr=$_;}'
```

It produced something like this with my data (a database restore log):

```
COPY 9
COPY 0
... (+2)
COPY 5
COPY 0
... (+1)
COPY 24
ALTER TABLE
... (+23)
CREATE INDEX
... (+73)
```